# Improve performance of speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition

Could anyone recommend good  speech pre-processing/filtering  algorithms/methods that would improve the performance of my speech recognition. I have been primarily been doing image processing related stuff and hence am not much aware of  speech pre-processing methods.

I am currently using Google's Web Speech API for speech to text recognition. This is the current flow of things.

- Take input from microphone
- Segment the audio using Voice Activity Detection. This is done since Google's API has a limit on the length of the segment it can process.
- Send the segment to Google's web speech API (on a thread)
- Print the response of the API

Using this I could only get up to 60-65% conversion accuracy. Is there any way to improve this? Would doing a pre-processing on the audio (noise-removal, filtering, etc.) help?

Comment: Please be clear about your question. DSP.SE is not a forum but a formal Q&A site. It will welcome all questions where you apply signal processing algorithms. A simplest answer to your above question is - now that you know Google API gives 60% accuracy, try a better algorithm! Please ask only a specific question pertaining to specific algorithm.

Comment: I am not aware of 'regular' speech pre-processing methods (if they are used). Also if someone has already used this API with more success, I would like to know what steps they had taken to make it work.

Comment: OK. I have requested for reopen of the question.